# Inner div affected by outer div's onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Problem:** 
Clicking of the inner div triggers the onClick-event of the outer div. In this case it toggles the visibility of the outer `<div>`, inner `<div>` and the `<p>` element.

**What I've tried:**
Setting the **z-index** higher on the inner div than the outer div. No effect.

**HTML:**

```
<div id='messageForm' onClick=toggleMessageForm() >
  <div class="innerBox">

    <p>Hi!</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function toggleMessageForm(){
  $('#messageForm').toggle();
}
```

*Note: The reason I'm using toggle() instead of show() is because I am using the same function when initially showing the form from a button in the original webpage.*

Comment: Why you need to use inline event handler? That to when you are using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `onClick` attribute entirely, and instead hook up the handler with jQuery:

```
$("#messageForm").click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    toggleMessageForm();
});
```

Put that in a `script` element lower down in the HTML than the `div` (or wrap it in a `ready` handler).

[`evt.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) cancels the bubbling (stops the propagation) of the click event, so it doesn't reach the parent div.

If you really, really want to keep the `onClick` attribute, you can do this instead:

```
<div id='messageForm' onClick="toggleMessageForm(event);">
```

...and then in `toggleMessageForm`:

```
function toggleMessageForm(evt){
  if (evt.stopPropagation) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
  }
  else {
      evt.cancelBubble = true;
  }
  $('#messageForm').toggle();
}
```

...but as you're already using jQuery, that would be unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)**();

```
function toggleMessageForm(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
  $('#messageForm').toggle();
}
```

### e.stopPropagation();

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Answer (score 0):

if you have one or more jQuery click functions on outer and inner div and you want to be performed only one of them (for example outer div) use **stopImmediatePropagation** function of jQuery:

```
$("#messageForm").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $('#messageForm').toggle();
});
```