# Prevent click on outer li while clicking on inner link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some `li`s including `a` links as below

```
<li>
  <span>SomeText</span>
  <a href='someurl' class='entityDetailModal'>sometext</a>
</li>
```

I am using a third party library ('LightGallery') that adds `click` event on `Li`, and by `Jquery` I have add `click` event to the links to show a dialog. 
The problem is when I click on link both click event will be fired,

my click event handler is

```
$('body').on("click", 'a.entityDetailModal', function (event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    event.stopPropagation();
    loadDialog(this, event, '#mainContainer', true, true, false); 
    return false; 
});
```

I tried `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault();` and `return false;` in link onclick event handler but they don't work.

Sample:http://jsfiddle.net/HuKab/30/

How can I overcome this?

### Update

It seems the problem is the way I add click event handler,
using this way it seems that everything is ok

```
$('a.entityDetailModal').click(function (event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    event.stopPropagation();
    loadDialog(this, event, '#mainContainer', true, true, false); 
    return false; 
});
```

### Update 2

Thanks @Huangism, this post [stackoverflow.com/questions/16492254/pros-and-cons-of-using-e-stoppropagation-to-prevent-event-bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492254/pros-and-cons-of-using-e-stoppropagation-to-prevent-event-bubbling) is explaining the reason.

Comment: Show the js code, which third party library?

Comment: Can you recreate a simple version of this in a fiddle? stopPropagation() should be able to fix this

Comment: @RezaRahmati I have fixed it in the comment of Bala's answer

Comment: this question was answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697305/inner-div-affected-by-outer-divs-onclick/24697483#24697483

Comment: @Jai check http://jsfiddle.net/HuKab/22

Comment: @Huangism yup correct. the issue was typo....`;)`

Answer (score 4):

Use stopPropagation(); in child element

```
 $("li").click(function (e) {

    alert("li");
});

$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();     // stop the default action if u need 
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("a");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HuKab/20/)

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/HuKab/22/ it's `e.preventDefault()` not `e.preventDefaults()` check your actual code to see if you made this typo or not

Comment: `return false;` does both;

Comment: @Huangism Thanks for correcting dictation, but it still doesn't work see http://jsfiddle.net/HuKab/23/

Comment: @RezaRahmati You STILL have `preventDefaults` please check your code carefully. Check the code on your computer and see if this is the issue if so then you should delete the question as it is caused by a typo

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HuKab/28/ see that link now .. sorry i used again ur same mistake. should not use two click event for same element you have to use either inline or JS

Comment: @Huangism  Yes I get it, but it doesn't work in my code, I'm going through my code to see what is wrong :)

Comment: @RezaRahmati you could update the question with more code if needed

Comment: @Huangism Would you see this link too: http://jsfiddle.net/HuKab/30/
The way I add click is different, and it doesn't work too.

Comment: @RezaRahmati does the click of the anchor need to be bound to the body?

Comment: @Huangism yes I need it

Comment: @RezaRahmati have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492254/pros-and-cons-of-using-e-stoppropagation-to-prevent-event-bubbling  I would suggest you to bind the click to the anchor alone AFTER the modal is initialized. This way it is only bound when there is a potential it will be used. Binding to body too much will slow down performance at some point since it is triggered every time something is clicked. It is a better approach and will solve your current issue

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear to me what your problem really is. If you simply want to get rid of the click on the `li` tag you may use `.unbind()` from jQuery (see: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/). You should end up with only your click event.

Another thing that might help is to use something like:

```
$("a").on('click.myContext', function(event) {
    //Your action goes here
}
```

This way you can have parallel events and turn them on with `$("a").on('click.myContext')` and off with  `$("a").off('click.myContext')`

Edit: Use:

```
$("a").on('click.myContext',function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("a");
});
```

see working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bGBLz/4/

Comment: My problem is : I want to click on link and I don't want li click event fired, while I want if I click on li (not link) li click fires

Comment: Thanks, the problem is the way I bind the click handler, see http://jsfiddle.net/bGBLz/5/